# Передача массивов в C++

Tags: массивы, c++, функции

Задача: написать функцию сортировки массива слиянием. Обязательно нужно передавать в эту функцию 2 массива, а на выходе получать слитый массив.

Насколько я знаю, в С++ массив возвращать нельзя. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как лучше поступить в этом случае, и каким образом мне получать после вызова функции готовый отсортированный массив?

Comment: Совсем не возвращать массив - нельзя) Он явно или не явно будет!

Можно:

1. возвращать ссылку на массив)
2. создать в функции отсортированный массив, перед выходом перезаписать исходные масивы

Comment: вот только какой язык программирования у Вас?

Comment: Тут у Вас два варианта:

1) Передать три аргумента (array1, array2, result_array)

2) Создать массив для результата в функции и вернуть его адрес (с отсортированным содержимым). (Только потом удалить (free()) его не забудьте).

Answer (score 2):

Внутри функции результирующий массив делаете через выделение памяти в куче и возвращаете указатель на него (т.е. через `new` или `malloc()` — обязательно; если объявите его как локальный, т.е. в стеке, то при выходе из функции он будет потерян).

Answer (score 0):

Можно массивы передать по ссылке(через указатель) и результат слияния списать в один из 2-х переданных массивов. После вызова функци в  нем и будет результат.
int a[],b[];
ввод массивов
slian(a,b);
Результат будет или в a или в b как вы сделаете при реализации функции слияния.
А можно описать глобальный массив и в него сливать(но это не очень)

Comment: Ну вот сколько можно объяснять: ССЫЛКИ И УКАЗАТЕЛИ - ЭТО РАЗНЫЕ ВЕЩИ!!!

Comment: Параметры в фуцнкцию можно передавать по ссылке или по значению. В языке С++ имя массива является адресом первого элемента массива и передаем мы в функцию адрес, а принимаем в функции его в переменную, которая является указателем на адрес. Вроде бы такой солидный дядечка, а такие вещи не знает.

Comment: Так передаем указатель на начало массива? Или что?

Comment: Уважаемый @duha6, вот посмотрите что вы пишите: "Можно массивы передать по ссылке(через указатель)". Так что из Вашего текста однозначно следует, что для Вас указатель и ссылка - одно и то же. А в С++ параметры можно передавать 3 способами: по значению, через ссылку и через указатель. Учитесь.

Comment: Ссылка - это тоже самое, что и указатель, просто синтаксический сахар. Часто говорят про передачу "по ссылке", имея в виду передачу "не по значению".

Comment: Внутри может быть все что угодно, но как элемент языка ссылка - это по сути псевдоним для другой переменной. Однако, как бы то ни было, с точки зрения знания и понимания языка, путать и смешивать ссылку и указатель совершенно неправильно.

Кстати, не всегда ссылка реализуется именно как указатель, т.е. как отдельная область памяти, содержащая адрес другой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать класс-обёртку над массивом, либо использовать умные указатели. Ещё как вариант можно использовать vector, но при возврате будут лишние затраты на копирование и лишнее выделение памяти. В новом стандарте C++, частично поддерживаемом в Visual C++ 2010 и в новых версиях GCC, есть rvalue-ссылки, оптимизирующие такие случаи.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `vector` и передавать ссылки.

Comment: Если в практической задаче удобнее использовать вектора. А здесь, ясно дело, чисто учебная задача на работу с массивами.